# expected declaration, found 'IDENT' item

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

Im writing a small code using Memcache Go API to Get data stored in one of its keys . Here are few of lines of code i used ( got the code from [Go app-engine  docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/memcache/) )

```
import "appengine/memcache"

item := &memcache.Item {
Key:   "lyric",
Value: []byte("Oh, give me a home"),
}
```

But the line 2 gives me a compilation error  ***"expected declaration, found 'IDENT' item"***

I'm new to Go , not able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `:=` [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) can only be used inside functions.

So either put the `item` variable declaration inside a function like this:

```
import "appengine/memcache"

func MyFunc() {
    item := &memcache.Item {
        Key:   "lyric",
        Value: []byte("Oh, give me a home"),
    }
    // do something with item
}
```

Or make it a global variable and use the `var` keyword:

```
import "appengine/memcache"

var item = &memcache.Item {
    Key:   "lyric",
    Value: []byte("Oh, give me a home"),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but the reason was completely different.

I was using following package name.

`package go-example`

Seems like, it's not a valid package name. After removing the hyphen, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error also shows up when assigning value to a variable whose name is a keyword
Like using var:= 2
This also causes the error "expected declaration, found 'IDENT' item"
So correct the name and it will be fine